# How to assign List<> Object values to textBox (s)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I want to assign the values of the findFamily object to the different TextBox(s) i tried the following code but it's not working would you please suggest me a better way. Thanks in advance.

```
 private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SearchFamilyMemberId.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            SITDataDataContext con = new SITDataDataContext();
            List<Family> findFamily = (from s in con.Families where s.FamilyMemberId.Equals(SearchFamilyMemberId.Text.Trim()) select s).ToList();
            if (findFamily.Any())
            {
                FamilyMemberId.Text = findFamily[0];
                FirstName.Text = findFamily[1];
                LastName.Text = findFamily[2];
                if (findFamily[3]=="Male")
                {
                    Male.IsChecked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Female.IsChecked = true;
                }
                Phone.Text = findFamily[4];
                Address.Text = findFamily[5];

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Family Id not found!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Id!");
        }
    }
```

here is my xamal code

```
 <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Family Member ID:"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="First Name:"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Last Name:"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Content="Gender:"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Content="Phone:"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Content="Address:"/>

        <CheckBox Name="ColonyResident" Content="Colony Resident" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Checked="ColonyResident_Checked" Unchecked="ColonyResident_Unchecked"/>
        <TextBox Name="SearchFamilyMemberId" IsEnabled="False" SelectionChanged="FamilyMemberId_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3"/>
        <TextBox Name="FamilyMemberId"  IsEnabled="False" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBox Name="FirstName" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBox Name="LastName" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <RadioButton Name="Male"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Content="Male" />
        <RadioButton Name="Female" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Margin="3" Content="Female" />
        <TextBox Name="Phone" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBox Name="Address" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <Button Name="Search" IsEnabled="False" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="3" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Search" Click="Search_Click"/>
        <Button IsDefault="True" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Add" Click="Add_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2" Margin="3" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Clear" Click="Clear_Click"/>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

use foreach loop through list as:

```
foreach(var a in findFamily)
{

    txtbox.text=a[0].tostring();

    txtbox2.text=a[1].tostring();

}
```

or use:

```
 txtbox.text = findFamily.Select(a => a[0].ToString()).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use data binding?

For each of the text boxes that you have, bind your `TextBox.Text` to its corresponding property in the view model, something like this:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding FirstName} />
```

Then, assign your `FirstName`, `LastName`...etc. properties to values and raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` for each of the properties (your view model should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and your view (i.e. UI) should get updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with any of the answers posted here. The question doesn't seem to be correct.

If you have a list of Family members. Then how can you show it as a single item.  How do you know which item you want to display.

Hence my suggestion is to use a listbox and using data binding,  create a view to display the current selected Family member's data in that view.